# Angular $http.post 1.6.1 not passing data to WebAPI

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

All, I just created a new Angular package using 1.6.1 but now the data doesn't seem to pass to my WebAPI.   However, when I post bits via SoapUI or something like that, everything is fine.

The Javascript looks like this:

```
function testapi()
        {
            var serviceRoot='http://server/testangular16/api/Values';

            var deferred=$q.defer();

            var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: serviceRoot,
                data: 'PassInTheText'
            };

            $http(req).then(goodResponse,badResponse);

            return deferred.promise;
        };
    function goodResponse(response)
    {
        console.log("Good response");
        console.log(response);

    }

    function badResponse(response)
    {
        console.log("Bad response");
        console.log(response);
    }
```

and the webapi is a very simple C# controller:

```
    // POST api/values
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage rp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        rp.Content = new StringContent(value);

        return rp;
    }
```

I am making it into the controller, I can set a break point and hit the parts where I can look at the value.  It's always null.

Looking at the network trace, the angular part does do a preflight and I can see the 200 response back.

```
Request URL:http://server/testangular16/api/Values
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:10.7.14.209:80
**Response Headers view source**
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8000
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 03 Feb 2017 18:09:04 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:"Management Corporation"
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
**Request Headers view source**
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:mjvzrx3
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

So, it looks like I'm passing CORS, but when I get to trying to pass the data in as the content of the post, it doesn't make it.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Web API expects an object in the message body, you cant pass in a primitive type unless you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content-type and prefix the value with an equals `=` sign.

So you can fix it by one of these methods

1. Adjust the c# parameter and turning it into a type that has a string property and then send in a json object with a matching parameter name.
2. Change the request to url-encoding content type and add a `=` to the variable value.
3. Send it as a part of the URL instead of the message body, you can still use the POST method.

---

#### Change to form-urlencoded

```
function testapi()
{
    var serviceRoot='http://server/testangular16/api/Values';
    var deferred=$q.defer();

    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: serviceRoot,
        data: '=PassInTheText', // added =
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' // specify content type
    };

    $http(req).then(goodResponse,badResponse);
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: I guess something doesn't add up then.   The only place I seem to need an = sign is if I'm calling from Angular 1.6.  I just tried in postman and I didn't have to do anything extra at all.   The body is just "Some Dummy Text".  Same thing with SoapUI.   If I use it to post the data and the body is the same then everything works fine.   That's leading me to believe it's really something in Angular 1.6, not so much WebAPI.   Also, I'm sending in my content type as application/json.....

Comment: And I just rolled back to Angular 1.5.11 and it works like it has... So, only variable is Angular 1.6....

Comment: <Ok, I gotta go look up how to post code in comments>

Comment: I'm going to restart from scratch and see if I can repeat.   Otherwise I'll probably end up converting to the answer I posted

Answer (score 0):

It seems if I do this, it works as expected.... Thoughts?

```
    // POST api/values
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var data = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Console.WriteLine("Data: {0}", data);

        HttpResponseMessage rp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        rp.Content = new StringContent("Data back from WebAPI" + data);

        return rp;
    }
```